Can't set -fbracket-depth parameter for PYMC model compilation
I'm trying to train a pymc model (version 4.4.0) on a Mac.  My model is fairly complex and it seems like the current level of complexity is causing the compiler some issues because I'm getting this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/vm.py", line 1246, in make_all
    node.op.make_thunk(node, storage_map, compute_map, [], impl=impl)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/op.py", line 131, in make_thunk
    return self.make_c_thunk(node, storage_map, compute_map, no_recycling)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/op.py", line 96, in make_c_thunk
    outputs = cl.make_thunk(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/basic.py", line 1202, in make_thunk
    cthunk, module, in_storage, out_storage, error_storage = self.__compile__(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/basic.py", line 1122, in __compile__
    thunk, module = self.cthunk_factory(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/basic.py", line 1647, in cthunk_factory
    module = cache.module_from_key(key=key, lnk=self)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/cmodule.py", line 1229, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/basic.py", line 1546, in compile_cmodule
    module = c_compiler.compile_str(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/cmodule.py", line 2640, in compile_str
    raise CompileError(
aesara.link.c.exceptions.CompileError: Compilation failed (return status=1):
/usr/bin/clang++ -dynamiclib -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -Wno-c++11-narrowing -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -fPIC -undefined dynamic_lookup -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/include/python3.9 -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/c_code -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib -fvisibility=hidden -o /Users/jisom/.aesara/compiledir_macOS-14.6.1-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.9.19-64/tmpen3swcx7/m0a2528786de976e08afd4eedf68e78061251bf4ba46bb89dfee1a310f6da39eb.so /Users/jisom/.aesara/compiledir_macOS-14.6.1-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.9.19-64/tmpen3swcx7/mod.cpp
/Users/jisom/.aesara/compiledir_macOS-14.6.1-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.9.19-64/tmpen3swcx7/mod.cpp:31954:32: fatal error: bracket nesting level exceeded maximum of 256
        if (!PyErr_Occurred()) {
                               ^
/Users/jisom/.aesara/compiledir_macOS-14.6.1-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.9.19-64/tmpen3swcx7/mod.cpp:31954:32: note: use -fbracket-depth=N to increase maximum nesting level
1 error generated.

The error recommends that I "use -fbracket-depth=N to increase maximum nesting level".  I've tried to add that flag to my code several ways.  I've tried adding
export CFLAGS="-fbracket-depth=1024"
export CXXFLAGS="-fbracket-depth=1024"

to my .zshrc.  I've tried adding this
os.environ['CFLAGS'] = "-fbracket-depth=1024"
os.environ['CXXFLAGS'] = "-fbracket-depth=1024"

to my python code before compiling the model.  I've even tried adding it this way in python code as well:
aesara.config.cxx = "/usr/bin/clang++ -fbracket-depth=1024"

When I try to add it using environment variables (the first 2 ways) it doesn't seem to get recognized at all and I get the same error as before.  When I add it to aesara.config.cxx I get this error instead:
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
/usr/bin/clang++ -fbracket-depth=1024 -dynamiclib -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -Wno-c++11-narrowing -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -fPIC -undefined dynamic_lookup -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/include/python3.9 -I/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aesara/link/c/c_code -L/opt/miniconda3/envs/ic_labor/lib -fvisibility=hidden -o /Users/jisom/.aesara/compiledir_macOS-14.6.1-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.9.19-64/tmptuxtqjuk/mba10987274f369529454d4a60996746c3927712a0b1b3928446a3c275151e2ee.so /Users/jisom/.aesara/compiledir_macOS-14.6.1-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.9.19-64/tmptuxtqjuk/mod.cpp 

Regardless, I need to find a way to actually modify this parameter during the compilation of my model.  How can I do that?

Try adding it like this:
aesara.config.gcc__cxxflags = f"-fbracket-depth={fbracket_depth}"
aesara.config.cxx = "/usr/bin/clang++"

Does that work?

Tried it and it didn't work
